Checking Dell Command Update for a registry value in Automox
Trying to create an evaluation script that will check registry key data. If the data is other than ScanDownloadApplyNotify, it will proceed to the remediation code.
Still new to powershell and I have tried a few variations. Thanks for any help.
#Pre-Defined registry key
$regPath = 'HKLM: \SOFTWARE\DELL\UpdateService\Clients\CommandUpdate\Preferences\Settings\Schedule\AutomationMode'

#Pre-Defined registry value
$regName = 'ScanDownloadApplyNotify'

$exists = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regPath" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $Value).$regValue

If ($exists -eq $regName)
{
    Write-Output "The registry key was found. Flagging for remediation to determine the key's value."
    Exit 1
}

Else
{
    Write-Output "The registry value was not found. Now exiting."
    Exit 0
} 





Note: For conceptual clarity, the variables used in the question have been renamed:
$regKeyPath is a registry key path such as 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\DELL\UpdateService\Clients\CommandUpdate\Preferences\Settings\Schedule'
and $regValueName is the name of a key's value, such as 'AutomationMode' (a property in PowerShell) that contains data (a property value in PowerShell terms).
Use Get-ItemPropertyValue to directly retrieve the data of interest:
# Retrieve the data stored in the value (property)
# and effectively default to $null, if it or the registry key
# as a whole doesn't exist (or an unexpected error occurs).
$propVal = 
  try { Get-ItemPropertyValue -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $regKeyPath -Name $regValueName } 
  catch { }

# Check if data (a property value) was found.
if ($null -ne $propVal) { "Value `"$regValueName`" contains: $propVal" }
else { Write-Warning "Value `"$regValueName`" or key `"$regKeyPath`" not found, or an unknown error occurred." }

Note:

The try ... catch is necessary, because the cmdlet, as of PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.4.x,  situationally and mistakenly reports a (statement-)terminating error rather than a non-terminating one. If it behaved properly, -ErrorAction Ignore alone would be sufficient.

See GitHub issue #5906 for the relevant bug report.




The above ignores both the case where the key doesn't exist and the case where it exists, but lacks the value (property) of interest, as well as any other errors.
To distinguish these conditions, more work is needed:
# Retrieve the data stored in the value (property)
# and effectively default to $null in case of error.
$propVal = 
  try { Get-ItemPropertyValue -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $regKeyPath -Name $regValueName } 
  catch {
    switch -Wildcard ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId) {
      'PathNotFound,*' { $keyMissing = $true }
      'Argument,*'     { $propertyMissing = $true }
      default          { <# Unexpected error, re-throw #> throw }
    }
  }

# Check if data (a property value) was found; if not, distinguish
# the failure reasons.
if ($null -ne $propVal)   { "Value `"$regValueName`" of key `"$regKeyPath`" contains: $propVal" }
elseif ($keyMissing)      { Write-Warning "Key `"$regKeyPath`" not found." }
elseif ($propertyMissing) { Write-Warning "Key `"$regKeyPath`" has no `"$regValueName`" value." }


As for what you tried:

(Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regKeyPath" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $regValueName).$regValueName

You don't need both a Select-Object -ExpandProperty call and property access (.$regValueName); try:

Either:

Get-ItemProperty $regKeyPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
  Select-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ExpandProperty $regValueName


Or:

(Get-ItemProperty $regKeyPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).$regValueName 

However, Get-ItemPropertyValue, as shown at the top, is more efficient:

Since your Get-ItemProperty calls do not specify a -Name argument, all the values are retrieved from the target registry key.

While you could mitigate that by passing -Name $regValueName to Get-ItemProperty too, this requires the awkward duplication of additionally having to access a property named for the value of $regValueName, leaving aside that Get-ItemProperty having to construct a custom object to report the result is overkill if all you care about is the property value (the registry value's data).

It is this awkwardness - discussed in this post - that the introduction of
Get-ItemPropertyValue in PowerShell v5 was meant to address.




Thanks mklement0, I decided to go a different route with the information you provided. This one works perfect!
$regPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\DELL\UpdateService\Clients\CommandUpdate\Preferences\Settings\Schedule'
$automationMode = $null

Try {
    $automationMode = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regPath -Name "AutomationMode"
} 
Catch { 
    Write-Output "Error retrieving AutomationMode property: $_"
}

Finally {
    if ($automationMode -eq 'ScanDownloadApplyNotify') {
        Write-Output 'The value of AutomationMode is currently ScanDownloadApplyNotify. No action taken.'
    } 
    elseif ($automationMode -eq 'ScanDownloadNotify') {
        Write-Output 'The value of AutomationMode is currently ScanDownloadNotify. Setting to ScanDownloadApplyNotify.'
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name "AutomationMode" -Value 'ScanDownloadApplyNotify'
    } 
    elseif ($automationMode -eq $null) {
        Write-Output 'The key does not exist, adding value.'
        New-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name "AutomationMode" -Value 'ScanDownloadApplyNotify' -PropertyType String
    }
}

